# What's the difference between physics and didactics of physics?

Tags: education

Do physics and didactics of physics intersect? Does one of them include the other? Is a doctor of didactics of physics supposed to do a postdoctoral research in physics?

Comment: Are you asking what the difference between a physicist and a physics teacher is? If so, do you mean a physics school teacher? Most research physicists also teach physics undergrads or graduates.

Comment: Would [academia.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Richard Feynman said he enjoyed teaching physics because it kept him focused on problems and also because he couldn't think of new ideas every day, week or month. Its why he refused a tenure at the Advanced Institute - there was no teaching duties there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, people who study physics, and who do postgraduate research in physics, are gearing up to do physics professionally in some form or another; this can be in the form of research in physics and other physical sciences, applications in industry, or a looser cloud of applications such as data analysis or science communications. Some people also go into teaching without formal training in how to teach; this sometimes works great, and sometimes it can be catastrophic for the students involved.

People who study *didactics* of physics will generally learn some physics as such, but the main focus of the study is how to *teach* physics. This can be at any level, from primary school through to university students.

As an added layer on top of that, someone with a *doctorate* in the didactics of physics implies that they research how physics should best be taught. The field of research on the didactics of physics is a smaller field than either didactics of physics and research on physics, but you do find research postgraduate programs in didactics of physics; there is e.g. [one in the University of Copenhagen](http://www.ind.ku.dk/english/research/didactics-of-physics/) whose self-description paints a better picture of the field than I could:

> Description
>
> The research group 'Didactics of Physics' investigates subject specific issues related to the teaching of physics at all levels. The group is particularly interested in learning difficulties and teaching strategies associated with the intrinsic mathematical character of physics. Furthermore, a strong emphasis is given to historical and epistemological investigations of the interplay between physics and mathematics.
>
> Examples of research questions
>
> - What characterizes good explanations in didactical settings (e.g. lectures, textbooks) that highlight the structural role of mathematics in physics?
> - How can historical and philosophical studies on the relationship between mathematics and physics improve the teaching of these disciplines?
> - What are typical difficulties to understand the application of mathematical concepts and structures (e.g. matrices, complex numbers, vector calculus, etc.) in physics? What are appropriate teaching strategies to circumvent them?

Generally speaking, someone who graduates from a research PhD in didactics of physics will not generally be considered for hiring as a postdoctoral researcher in physics without additional training ─ in the same way that your generic condensed-matter physicist will struggle getting hired if they want to change fields to, say, general relativity, without field-specific training.

The question of whether physics and its didactics intersect is ultimately a matter of opinion, and frankly I don't find it that interesting ─ the only concrete thing that tends to come out of trying to artificially carve the knowledge into neat parcels is that people working on what have now been decreed to be 'edges' get their work made harder for them, for no good reason at all.

Comment: It might help those looking for didactics programs to know that in the US the research field is often called "Physics Education Research" and abbreviated as "PER".

Comment: @dmckee Yeah, that'd explain why the first Google hit on "PhD in didactics of physics" came out in Denmark. Presumably the UK and other English-speaking countries also use slightly different terminology.